# Keeping unmatched data in query

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a query I'm trying to run across two tables. Let's simplify and say they are

Table1

```
| Name    | Type |
+---------+------+
| Sam     | A    |
| Jane    | A    |
| Steve   | B    |
```

Table2

```
| Name    | Value | Date |
+---------+-------+------+
| Sam     | 2     | 2014 |
| Jane    | 2     | 2013 |
| Sam     | 1     | 2013 |
| Steve   | 1     | 2013 |
```

I want to make a list of people with type A, simple enough:

```
SELECT name FROM table1 WHERE type='A'
```

which gives

```
Sam
Jane
```

as expected. I also want to include their most recent date from Table2:

```
SELECT name, MAX(date)
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 USING(name)
WHERE type='A'
GROUP BY name
```

which gives

```
Sam  2014
Jane 2013
```

But I don't want to include items in Table2 unless they have value 1:

```
SELECT name, MAX(date)
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 USING(name)
WHERE type='A' && value = 1
GROUP BY name
```

which gives

```
Sam  2013
```

But here I want to keep all matching names, like so:

```
Sam  2013
Jane NULL
```

How can I do this? I should mention that both tables involved are large, even though the output is not (a few hundred) so efficiency is a concern, though not a huge concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move your `WHERE` criteria to the `JOIN` as putting it in the `WHERE` clause negates the `OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT t.name, MAX(t2.date)
FROM table1 t
     LEFT JOIN table2 t2 on t.name = t2.name and t2.value = 1
WHERE t.type='A'
GROUP BY t.name
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/844a8/1)

Comment: Beautifully simple. Thanks!